# C# method from List to List

Tags: c#

I made a list of cars, the factory produces every 4 cars broken (`public bool Broken;`).

**My code**

```
public static void BuildCar()
{

    List<Factory> cars = new List<Factory>();

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Factory newCars = new Cars("string", "string", "bool");
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        {
            newCars.Broken = true;
            cars.Add(newCars);
        }
        else
        {
            newCars.Broken = false;
            cars.Add(newCars);
        }
    }
}
```

**What I did**

> A list of all the cars (good and broken).

**What I need to do**

> Create a method that copies only good cars to another list.

Thx.

Comment: "sends me from the car list to another list"? Do you mean to add only unbroken cars to a separate list? If so, can't you add the unbroken cars to the second list directly in your existing code?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please provide how you want your output to look like ?

Comment: `===` is not a C# operator

Comment: `List<Factory> goodCars = newCars.Where(car => !car.Broken).ToList()`?

Comment: @KhalilLazhar as OP asked for a list :)

Comment: public List<Factory> GetGoodCars(List<Factory> cars) {return cars.Where(car => !car.Broken).ToList()};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ query:

```
var goodCars = cars.Where(car => !car.Broken).ToList();
```

Comment: Avoid ToList() operator , just use where opertor who returns a lazily evaluated sequence - no copying is required

Comment: @KhalilLazhar Why do you keep referring to methods as `operators`?

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Microsoft call them Standard Query Operators :))

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne if you want to call them methods then call them extension methods :))

Comment: Which is exactly what I do call them.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne technically they are an extensions methods.. we call them specially operators in LINQ ....

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way probably:

```
List<Factory> goodCars = cars.FindAll(car => !car.Broken);
```

Comment: 'Where' is faster than 'FindAll' , where opertor returns a lazily evaluated sequence - no copying is required like 'FindAll'